# useQuery: Attempted to assign to readonly property

Tags: javascript, react-native, hook, gql

I get data from `useQuery`.
And I want to sort them by data field `directFeedNumber`.

```
  const { data: allFeedData, loading: allFeedLoading } =
    useQuery(SEE_ALL_FEED_ORDER);

  const FeedSort = allFeedData.seeAllFeedOrder.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
```

So I use `sort` function to do this, but when I console.log `FeedSort`, it says **Attempted to assign to readonly property.**

So can't I use `sort` function with data got from `useQuery`?

Then how can I sort them? Please help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) alters the original array, unlike other methods such as [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which produce a new array.

In order to prevent this, we can make a shallow copy of the original array.

**Example:**

```
const { data: allFeedData, loading: allFeedLoading } = useQuery(SEE_ALL_FEED_ORDER);

const FeedSort = [...allFeedData.seeAllFeedOrder].sort(function (a, b) {
   return a - b;
});
```

What we do here is create a new array and populate it with the values of the original array using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Then we sort the newly created array, which we can alter.

---

**Note:** there are also other ways of making shallow copies, or deep copies for that matter, of arrays and objects.
[Here are some other examples](https://holycoders.com/javscript-copy-array/).